# How do I get rid of the small nub in the bottom right corner of my terminal?

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, gnome-terminal, xmonad

I'm setting up XMonad within Linux Mint, and I've been able to remove the menubar and the scrollbar from my terminal windows, but I can't get rid of the small resizing nub in the bottom right corner. Here's a screenshot: [image: terminal with offending nub]

I think it's feature of Linux Mint (maybe?), but it serves no purpose because of the nature of XMonad, so I'd love to get rid of it. It's gnome-terminal, by the way. I assume that's important.

Edit: Ok, it's a feature of gnome-terminal, because xterm and rxvt don't have it. So I guess my question is: How can I remove the nub from gnome-terminal? One answer is just "use a different emulator", but I'm hoping there's a way to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gnome-terminal program sticks that nub there itself.  It started doing that sometime during the transition to Gnome3, and when I realized it wasn't my window manager or desktop environment but the program itself, I was annoyed enough that I looked for an alternative.

<strike>[Roxterm](http://roxterm.sourceforge.net) is currently my terminal emulator of choice.</strike>

[UPDATE]: I'm back to using gnome-terminal.  More recent versions of gnome-terminal (or perhaps GTK?) no longer add the nub, and the Roxterm maintainer has just [stopped development](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=827768) due to time constraints and a tricky incompatibility with recent GTK.

Comment: Baller, 5 minutes of configuration makes Roxterm look and act exactly like gnome-terminal. I'll wait a little while before accepting to see if anyone can actually get rid of the nub.

Answer (score 0):

Since Gnome-Terminal uses CSS you can simply add a css files that renders the corner differently.

Create the following file:

~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

In this file you write the following lines:

```
* {
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-height: 0;
    -GtkWindow-resize-grip-width: 0;
}
```

This will "remove" the resize grip, perfect if you don't want to change  terminal and lose the functionality of gnome-terminal.